# How to grep three expressions in same line

Tags: unix, tabs, grep

This is my first post so I hope I'll be clear enough and excuse me by advance if not.

Basically, I've got a lot of tab separated files (with 22 columns) and i want to filter out only the lines that match my expectations.

Here is what i have :

```
2   IP_251781.1 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Doubtful
2.1 IP_251781.1 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
2.1.1   IP_251781.1 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Confident
3   IP_05000.1  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Doubtful
3.1 IP_05000.1  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
3.1.1   IP_05000.1  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Doubtful
4   T19952  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Doubtful
4.1 T19952  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
4.1.1   T19952  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Doubtful
5   O29920  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Confident
5.1 O29920  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
5.1.1   O29920  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Confident
```

I want to get only the lines that have :

1. two dots in the first column AND
2. begins with IP_ and finishes by .1 in the second column AND
3. has "confident at the last column

With a grep command, I would like to get in return the following line :

```
2.1.1   IP_251781.1 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  Confident
```

I think grep would be able to do it but I don't know how to do it.

I guess there should be something like that

```
grep "^*.*.*" myfile.txt | grep "IP_*.1" myfile.txt | grep "Confident$" myfile.txt
```

Any idea ?

*** EDIT ***

I've got that command which works with the sample I provided.

```
grep -P "\d\.\d\.\d" rep.tsv | grep -P "Confident$"  | grep -P "IP_.*\.1"
```

However, My sample does not contain a subtility I have with my bigger files.
The second column can be occupied by more than one expression  that can be `IP_*.1, IP_*.1` OR `A59562, IP_*.1, P51262...` OR `A95956, P51516...` and I'd like to get only the **IP_*.1, IP_*.1** line.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` to perform multiple pattern matching on the columns:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~ /\..*\./ && $2 ~ /^(IP_.*\.1(, )?)+$/ && $NF ~ /Confident/ {print}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.

This solves partially my question.

The problem is the second column can contain more than one expression (and not only IP_*.1) and I want only those whith one (or many) IP_*.1 without anything else.

I think a solution would be to tell awk that there is a tab after the ".1" of the "IP*.1"? 

Is that possible ?
Thank you again

Comment: Not sure that I understood your point about "the second column can contain more than one expression". Could you give me a sample row?

Comment: Here is an example : `11.7.1 IP_158946.1, O001458, A8Z720 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 Confident
25.1.1 IP_288577.1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 Confident
26.1.1 IP_128379.1, IP_180135.1, IP_180971.1, IP_181000.1, IP_245225.1, IP_264312.1, IP_306310.1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 Confident
`I'd like to get line 1 and two. The command you gave with minor change `awk '$1 ~ /\..*\./ && $2 ~ /^IP_.*\.1$/  && $NF ~ /Confident/ {print}' ` gave only line 2.

Comment: Edit :: I'd like to get line 2 and 3.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to change `$2` with `$0`, which corresponds to the whole line. That would match at least one instance of `IP_.*\.1` .

Comment: @Vivi, please ignore my comment above. How do you determine the bounds of different columns in your file?

Comment: I'm note sure I understand the term "bounds". If you mean what separates columns, its a tab (but the `\t` wont work somehow).

Comment: Try changing `awk` with `awk -F'\t'` because default field separator is either tab or spaces.

Comment: `awk -F '\t' '$1 ~ /\..*\./ && $2 ~ /^IP_.*\.1/  && $NF ~ /Confident/ {print}' test.tsv`gave me all three lines

Answer (score 0):

Your guess has some mistakes:

```
grep "^*.*.*" myfile.txt | grep "IP_*.1" myfile.txt | grep "Confident$" myfile.txt
```

`*` is not any character but repeat character.
`.` is any character unless you escape the character.
`myfile.txt` is only needed for the first grep, the other greps will take input from the pipe.

Your guess can be corrected into the next command:

```
grep "^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" myfile.txt| grep "IP_.*\.1"  | grep "Confident$"
```

When you want them in one command, use (replace spaces between the double quotes with real tabs)

```
grep "^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*   IP_.*\.1        .*      Confident$" myfile.txt
```

**Edit:** Use `grep -P`

The grep option -P is useful for digits and tabs. When your grep supports -P, the above command can be simplified to

```
grep -P "^\d*\.\d*\.\d*\tIP_[^\t]*\.1\t.*\tConfident$" myfile.txt
```

Since the question has been edited, so is the answer:
You can use repeating matches in grep like this:

```
grep -P "^\d*\.\d*\.\d*\t(IP_[^\t, ]*\.1[, ]*)*\t.*\tConfident$" myfile.txt
```

Comment: Hey, thank uou for your answer. On the sample file i wrote, the following command `grep -P "\d\.\d\.\d" rep.tsv | grep -P "Confident$"grep -P "\d\.\d\.\d" rep.tsv | grep -P "Confident$"` gives me the two lines with *.*.* and confident (that's normal). However when I do `grep -P "\d\.\d\.\d" rep.tsv | grep -P "Confident$"  | grep -P "IP_.*\.1"`, it gives me the correct line but that wont work if there are other things than IP_*.1 inside the second column, i'll get them.